# Deciding on how to scale data and which scaler to use?

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, data-science, scaling

I am trying to train an MLP model with two Dense layers in keras to do prediction for a small data set of around 100 uni-variate time series. This model should get values of 6 days and predict the 7th day value. As an input to the model, I first concatenate these time series after each other in a dataframe like follow:

```
 ts1    val1 
 ts1    val2 
   ...     
 ts1    varN 
 ts2    val1 
 ts2    val2 
   ...     
 ts3    varN 
 ts3    val1 
 ts3    val2 
   ...     
 ts3    varN 
   ...
 ts100  val1 
 ts100  val2 
   ...     
 ts100  varN
```

I wonder what is the best way to scale this data? First of all, Should I scale each time series (ts_n) independently, so there will be 100 scalers at the end? Or should I better scale them all together (one acaler at the end) so that I won't lose the correlation between them? Or since all of these time series are considered as the same feature, then there is no point in having correlation?!

My second question is about which scaling method I should choose? min-max or StandardScaler (from sklearn)? Some time series behave quite different from the others, and they have big variations in their values. If I use min-max scaler, it will ignore these differences, right? So isn't it better to use StandardScaler that (hopefully) considers the differences in score between each time series?

P.S. I should mention that 'after' the scaling is done, I will create timesteps and will have the final results like this:

```
        timestep1 | timestep2 | timestep3 | timestep4 | timestep5 | timestep6 | timestep7
 ts1      var1    |   var2    |   var3    |   var4    |   var5    |   var6    |   var7    
 ts1      var2    |   var3    |   var4    |   var5    |   var6    |   var7    |   var8    
 ts1      var3    |   var4    |   var5    |   var6    |   var7    |   var8    |   var9
 ...
 ts2      var1    |   var2    |   var3    |   var4    |   var5    |   var6    |   var7    
 ts2      var2    |   var3    |   var4    |   var5    |   var6    |   var7    |   var8    
 ts2      var3    |   var4    |   var5    |   var6    |   var7    |   var8    |   var9
 ...
 ts100      var1    |   var2    |   var3    |   var4    |   var5    |   var6    |   var7    
 ts100      var2    |   var3    |   var4    |   var5    |   var6    |   var7    |   var8    
 ts100      var3    |   var4    |   var5    |   var6    |   var7    |   var8    |   var9
 ...
```

Comment: How different are the numbers? What happens if you don't scale them?

Comment: In some time series it varies from 0 to 1000, Some others from 10000 to like a million, so they are very different from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I've found very little difference in performance between MinMaxScaler and StandardScaler.  Of course, since (it appears) you'll be scaling your target variable, as well, you should make sure you use a scaler that is consistent with your output activation function.  For example, if you're output activation function is a ReLU, you wont be able to predict any negative values.  In that case, I would lean towards the MinMaxScaler since all of your targets will end up in the interval [0,1].

In terms of whether to scale the time series together or independently, it may depend on the specific setting.  If the scales tend to have different time-dependent behaviors, it's likely good to scale them together so the difference is preserved.  If they all behave with a similar pattern, scaling them independently will likely work best.

It's also worth considering other network architectures for time-series forecasting, e.g. RNNs.

Answer (score 1):

you need take care about MinMax Scale, because in a real situation you prediction data can have a diferente scale, in other words the can be greater than the highest value in the train set.

i think that standard scale is best in this case, because we put the mean=0(or a defined number) and std=0 or 1.

another thing that you can try too is make the first layer of network without activation and last layer too. or a relu if are not working with negative values.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I believe it depends on how your features are distributed. Try to plot the statistical distribution of all of your features and try to understand if most of them are somewhat normally distributed or not. If they are, then using the standard scaler will benefit the model, however, if you notice that your features do not tend to follow a normal distribution (or something close to it), then maybe it'd be better to use MinMax scaler. This is because if your features aren't normally distributed and you use Standard Scaler, you are forcing a normal distribution into a dataset which is not normally distributed and therefore that could led to high levels of overfitting and poor performance on unseen data.